# I have no ckeditor toolbar with Drupal7

Tags: drupal-7, ckeditor4.x

I have a website with Drupal 7.59.

I had ckeditor before upgrading and everything went fine. But now, I have no toolbar, even when I try to configure it, no toolbar shows up.

I tried to uninstall ckeditor, to install WYSIWYG module with ckeditor as a library, but it doesn't work.

I uninstalled WYSIWYG and reinstalled ckeditor (module and library), but nothing works.

What other things should I try or look for?

Comment: *It doesn't work* is not enough to diagnose the problem you're having.

Comment: Hello.Thanks for trying to help me..

Comment: When I say itvodesn(t work, it means I don't have the ckeditor toolbar.

Comment: When I look it to the administration-ckeditor-profile, I have an item where I should see the toolbar (where you can choose between basic-advanced and full) : but I have nothing here. And when I try to add content, I have no toolbar.

Comment: I found a solution on another website :The problem was with the JQuery Updates, the current version of WYSIWYG module (7.x-2.2) is not compatible with the latest JQuery version (v1.10 at this moment). So, I had to set the JQuery version to 1.8 and now the toolbar shows up. You can set this by visiting the following path: admin/config/development/jquery_update and it worked !